# Blogs and stories on Pentesting and Red Team engagements

Tags: penetration-test

I'm learning and thriving to be a Red Teamer. I'd like suggestions for stories and blogs to read on real Red Team/Pentest engagements (or just realistic one) such as [this](https://threader.app/thread/1063423110513418240).

The subject can be in any area of Pentesting. I am, however, mainly looking for articles on Physical, WebApp and Infiltration.

Comment: Unfortunately, open-ended questions like this are off-topic here.